# script using a while loop to check if a user already exists

Tags: bash

Need help with a script. The script will take in a list of names and assigned group from a text doc as an argument, then create unique usernames from the those names, random passwords, and home directories for given groups and users. I am stuck on matching the assigned group with the new username for that group and making a while loop that will test if the newly created usernames are already in the system, and if not, add the users and groups in the home directories. eg. /home/group/username.
I have made an if statement that will test if the user already exists, else add the user. I want to do this with a while loop instead of an if else.

The input is a text doc with multiple names listed in the following order
last first middleint group
example.

```
smith joe t student
barnes tom r manager
```

The script will take the first character from the first and last name and add three random numbers to those to create a unique user name for each name on the list. I have done this in the function `createLogin`. next, and where I am stuck, I need a while loop to test if the system already has the usernames `createLogin` has made and add the user and the group in the home directory.

```
if id -u $user >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    user=$(createLogin) # If user already exists, create new username
else
    # add new user and group. ie. /home/group/user`
```

Comment: It's not that clear what you want help with. Could you [edit] your question to clarify? Perhaps it would be useful to show a sample of your input, along with explaining how you would like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

function check_user_exists() {
    if id -u $1 >/dev/null 2>&1; then 
        # username exists - try another username and loop
        user=$(createLogin)
        check_user_exists $user
    else
        # create user
    fi
}

while read line
do
    user=$(createLogin)

    check_user_exists $user 
done
```

The `useradd` command also allows you to add new users to specific groups by name with the`-G` option.

Comment: This will help with the test. although, Now I am a little confused on how to add the user. I am using `useradd -G $group -d /home/$group/$user` where $group and $user are the variables that contain the specified group and user. This is not working.

Comment: You are missing the username from the command. `useradd $user -G $group -d /home/$group/$user/`.